# KEY_USAGE_BIT_INCORRECT SSL error IIS web service

Tags: android, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

Ihave a .NET api hosted in IIS web service with self signed certificate, and I have a mobile app that acces this api, But studently i got the KEY_USAGE_BIT_INCORRECT SSL error in some android phones but at the same time other phones work perfectly with no problem.
To make phones with error work i have to reset them.

I attach a capture of this error for more details.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: If you are using a self-signed certificate and encounter a "KEY_USAGE_BIT_INCORRECT" error, it is important to ensure that the certificate is configured correctly. This error usually occurs when the SSL certificate does not match the key usage specified in the certificate. You can try generating a new certificate to include the digital signature value, or remove the entire key usage extension.

Comment: For production use, it is recommended to obtain an SSL certificate from a trusted certification authority (CA) rather than using a self-signed certificate. Public CA certificates are recognized and trusted by all major platforms, including Android.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace the generated self-signed certificate with the one signed by some CA. You can use Let's Encrypt as the CA for free.

Download and install certbot tool from this [link](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/releases/latest/download/certbot-beta-installer-win_amd64_signed.exe).

Generate a certificate for your domain

```
certbot certonly --standalone -d your.domain.com
```

This command will generate 4 files (*fullchain.pem*, *chain.pem*, *privkey.pem* and *cert.pem*)
IIS Express can only use *.pfx* certificates, so you need to combine *cert.pem* and *privkey.pem* into a single certificate.pfx. The easiest way to do this is by using OpenSSL (you can download it from the [link](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)) with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem
```

You can now replace the self-signed certificate with your **signed** one.